# ERROR: No matching distribution found for win32clipboard

Tags: python, installation, terminal, module

I'm using python 3.9.5, when I tried to install `win32clipboard` on terminal, it showed me this error:

```
C:\Users\Admin>pip install win32clipboard
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement win32clipboard (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for win32clipboard
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You must download `pywin32` first as `win32clipboard` is part of that package.

Do so by running this in your command prompt:

`pip install pywin32`

Now you can try to install `win32clipboard` again and import it.